# interpretationInput variables ARIMA

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, stata, sas

Could anyone help me with the interpretation of the deltas:
[image]

*The dependent variable* lnY (with **y=number of calls**)  is differentiated 7 times, given a weekly seasonality.

*Independent variables:* 
**'vacances' (dummy for school holidays)** was differentiated 7 times and the following transfer function was used: input=(/(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)vacances ferie)

**'ferie' (dummy for public Holiday)** was not differentiated at all.

If I understand it well, the estimates for *school holidays* and *public holidays* can be interpreted as:

When 'vacances'=1, the nb of calls received is 10% lower than 7 days before.
When 'ferie' =1, the nb of calls received is 82% lower than on a 'normal day'

Could someone tell me the interpretation for the deltas?

PD:

Code sas

```
proc arima data= work.time; 
    identify var=lny(7) crosscorr=(vacances) noprint;
    estimate p=(7 14) input=(/(4  6 7 )vacances )noint method= ml;
    outlier id=date1;
    run;
```

A link to a general explanation of the transfer function I used.
[Rational transfer functions and Distributed lag Models](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/ets/chap7/sect14.htm)